# Variable Voltage Using PWM and Low Pass Filter

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, grounding, low-pass

I am trying to control a steady DC output voltage using a Micro controller with a PWM duty cycle. With the current schematic, the Voltage on `Vout` is pulsing along with the Mosfet at what ever the duty cycle is.  I know that this is the result of `Load` being grounded only when Mosfet is "on", but can not figure out how to get around this.  I want a smooth, controllable `Vout` that uses the same `ground` as the Fet. I know this is a noob question but any help will be appreciated. Also, I don't want to be picky but for me pictures really do speak a thousand words.

**Current Schematic**
[image]

**Simulation**
[image]

**EDIT**

What I'm really looking for is a way to use a low-pass filter to smooth a PWM voltage. This **smoothed out** voltage will then be used to power a 1 ohm load.  I know how to create a PWM voltage and a low pass filter, but not how to implement both to power something.  Since I'm new to circuits, a simple schematic drawing will be very helpful.

Comment: You're measuring the voltage at Vout rather than across the load.

Comment: The only way I could get the simulation to work was to put the load there.  I just want a smooth Vout that powers the load.

Comment: I want be able to change the load on the devise I am designing. It has to be 1 ohms.  I just need a way to ground it so that it want pulse.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm having a hard time explaining what I want.  Your solutions are noted, but not what I'm looking for.  I need a different design, not a change values.

Comment: do you really need to load a 1OHHM? at 2Vrms, thats 4 watts

Comment: I really need a 1 ohm load at 6 volts.  The device is designed to create a lot of heat.

Comment: Yes it will create heat as dissipation at the filter resistors, capacitors that should support the high RMS current you want. For that application you use LC filters (inductor/capacitor) not RC (resistor/capacitor). If the voltage output you want is lower than the input I suggest you read about **buck converters**.

Comment: If the load is just a 1 ohm heater, then I don't think you need a low pass filter.  The heater time constant will be longer than your ~20 uS period.  (the heater will do the averaging.)  So just bang on it with the FET.  Is it OK if the load floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to read theory of DC/DC (buck or boost) converters.
http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu31.php

Answer (score 2):

Here's one viable approach.. the buffer simulates the micro output. The output in this case is 0-Vdd = 0-5V and that is filtered and buffered and amplified by 1.6 to give 8V. I used 1kHz for this, but you can adjust resistor and cap values to suit. For precision, you can use an actual buffer and give it a separate reference supply. The op-amp type will depend on your requirements, but probably would be a rail-to-rail in and out capable of handling the desired output voltage.

Edit: If you're actually wanting a 1 ohm load, you'll also need a hefty power stage followingt hte op-amp. This is a separate question, really. The PWM gets you the analog voltage, but you want a really high current, so that voltage requires a power analog buffer stage.

P.S. You should be able to run the simulation on this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUIsxw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, note that the low-pass filter uses quite high value resistors to get the time constants and the op-amp does not load it. There are other possible approaches such as an LC filter that could run cooler and avoid the op-amp (in place of it would be a half-bridge power driver) but this is the one from me tonight that more closely follows your question.

Comment: I do not need to amplify the voltage, just adjust it variably. The devise is going to be high amps using high drain batteries.

Comment: You have an 8V source in your simulation. That is higher than most microcontroller PWM outputs (usually 3.3 or 5V).

Comment: I know that, I'm using the microcontrollers 5v output to control a 8v duty cycle.

Comment: And thus amplifying it, so you **do** need an amplifier.

Comment: And a microcontroller's output can be amplified to 30+ watts without using a external power source?

Comment: Of course not..

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your design is basic:

1. The series filtering resistors are too large, and they add inefficiencies. Use an inductor instead and thus filter with an LC circuit instead of RC.
2. The series filtering capacitors need to go to ground, not to the drain of the mosfet.
3. Once inductance is added, a freewheeling diode needs to be added to prevent spurious oscillations and large voltages generated when the MOSFET would open.

[image: example of an LC filter for a PWM power supply with a MOSFET switch]